# Solving an absolute value inequality without using a certain property of the absolute value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Can I solve this inequality:
$$|2x + 3| \leq 4$$ 
without using the property that $|x| \leq a$ is equivalent to $-a \leq x \leq a$ ?

Thanks!!

Comment: It is equivalent to $(2x + 3)^2 \leq 4^2$.

Comment: You absolutely want to make things more complicated than they are?

Comment: This is sick! "How can I compute the area of a rectangle without using that it is $a\cdot b$".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at

$2x+3>0 \implies 2x+3\leq 4$

and

$2x+3\leq 0 \implies -(2x+3)\leq 4$

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by splitting the cases:

- **case 1**: $2x+3>0$: In this case, $|2x+3|=2x+3$
- **case 2**: $2x+3<0$: In this case, $|2x+3|=-(2x+3)$

Answer (score 1):

$|x-a|$ it's a distance between $x$ and $a$ on the $x$-axis.

We need to solve that
$$|2x+3|\leq4$$ or
$$\left|x-\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\right|\leq2,$$
which gives
$$-3.5\leq x\leq0.5.$$
Draw it!